# I need to sign a binary stream with a certificate

Tags: java, signature, self-signed, private-key

I basically need to create a self signed certificate and then sign a binary stream with it to create a signature. I tried searching Google but i can't seem to get the right keywords for related results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looked for keytool.exe ?

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/pkg.html http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/pkg.html http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security.cert/pkg.html

Comment: http://traser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/traser/0.3/TraSer/src/net/sf/traser/common/KeystoreManager.java?revision=186&view=markup for certificate management

Comment: thx, at this point i guess i can make the self signed certificate (it seems similar to making a self signed SSL certificate) but i don't get what function call i can make that supplies the certificate and a string and then makes the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the private key, not the certificate to sign a stream.  Since you tagged this with Java, I am assuming you want to use the JCA.

Check out this example: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#SigEx

Comment: i finally understand what exactly i needed to do, i was supposed to create a PEM certificate so that it has both the rsa private key and the certficate in the .pem file (http://usefulfor.com/nothing/2009/06/10/x509-certificate-basics/)

adn then i wsa supposed to read in the file as a binary stream and make a Certficate block with it 
(http://clarens.sourceforge.net/docs/jclarens_apidoc/pk/edu/niit/clarens/util/CertificateBlock.html)

from there i can get the privatekey out and then use it as the privatekey as shown above.

Thx again, i thought i would just come back and add my full solution